How to get Graalvm to convert AWT Java program to exe
I've written a Java Chess program that plays fairly well. I wanted to use Graalvm to turn it into an exe so users wouldn't need to have Java installed to run it. A side benefit might be a little performance boost. The program compiles and runs fine from Java.
>javac chess.java
>jar -cfm chess.jar Manifest.txt *.class *.png *.wav *.txt *.ico
>java -jar chess.jar

It also compiles without errors using the native-image program.
>native-image -jar chess.jar
========================================================================================================================
GraalVM Native Image: Generating 'chess' (executable)...
========================================================================================================================
For detailed information and explanations on the build output, visit:
https://github.com/oracle/graal/blob/master/docs/reference-manual/native-image/BuildOutput.md
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[1/8] Initializing...                                                                                    (7.0s @ 0.10GB)
 Java version: 21.0.5+9-LTS, vendor version: Oracle GraalVM 21.0.5+9.1
 Graal compiler: optimization level: 2, target machine: x86-64-v3, PGO: ML-inferred
 C compiler: cl.exe (microsoft, x64, 19.41.34123)
 Garbage collector: Serial GC (max heap size: 80% of RAM)
 1 user-specific feature(s):
 - com.oracle.svm.thirdparty.gson.GsonFeature
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Build resources:
 - 11.45GB of memory (75.6% of 15.16GB system memory, determined at start)
 - 12 thread(s) (100.0% of 12 available processor(s), determined at start)
[2/8] Performing analysis...  [****]                                                                     (9.3s @ 0.65GB)
    6,687 reachable types   (80.1% of    8,346 total)
   11,647 reachable fields  (59.6% of   19,530 total)
   35,214 reachable methods (53.7% of   65,575 total)
    2,102 types,    49 fields, and 1,059 methods registered for reflection
       69 types,    52 fields, and    59 methods registered for JNI access
        3 native libraries: crypt32, ncrypt, version
[3/8] Building universe...                                                                               (2.0s @ 0.62GB)
[4/8] Parsing methods...      [**]                                                                       (3.1s @ 0.82GB)
[5/8] Inlining methods...     [***]                                                                      (0.5s @ 1.17GB)
[6/8] Compiling methods...    [****]                                                                    (18.1s @ 0.88GB)
[7/8] Laying out methods...   [**]                                                                       (2.8s @ 1.31GB)
[8/8] Creating image...       [**]                                                                       (2.7s @ 1.60GB)
  19.47MB (58.36%) for code area:    19,031 compilation units
  13.58MB (40.70%) for image heap:  192,870 objects and 65 resources
 319.64kB ( 0.94%) for other data
  33.36MB in total
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Top 10 origins of code area:                                Top 10 object types in image heap:
   9.02MB java.desktop                                         4.92MB byte[] for code metadata
   6.55MB java.base                                            2.54MB byte[] for java.lang.String
   2.33MB svm.jar (Native Image)                               1.51MB java.lang.String
 641.66kB chess.jar                                            1.15MB java.lang.Class
 197.62kB com.oracle.svm.svm_enterprise                      349.00kB byte[] for reflection metadata
 153.15kB java.logging                                       329.12kB byte[] for general heap data
  72.82kB java.prefs                                         313.45kB com.oracle.svm.core.hub.DynamicHubCompanion
  64.82kB jdk.accessibility                                  265.19kB java.util.HashMap$Node
  56.90kB java.datatransfer                                  235.79kB byte[] for embedded resources
  50.44kB jdk.proxy1                                         216.59kB char[]
 236.70kB for 10 more packages                                 1.79MB for 1244 more object types
                              Use '-H:+BuildReport' to create a report with more details.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Security report:
 - Binary includes Java deserialization.
 - Use '--enable-sbom' to embed a Software Bill of Materials (SBOM) in the binary.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Recommendations:
 PGO:  Use Profile-Guided Optimizations ('--pgo') for improved throughput.
 INIT: Adopt '--strict-image-heap' to prepare for the next GraalVM release.
 AWT:  Use the tracing agent to collect metadata for AWT.
 HEAP: Set max heap for improved and more predictable memory usage.
 CPU:  Enable more CPU features with '-march=native' for improved performance.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        3.7s (7.9% of total time) in 182 GCs | Peak RSS: 2.89GB | CPU load: 5.82
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Produced artifacts:
 C:\Users\mike_\Dropbox\Projects\Chess\awt.dll (jdk_library)
 C:\Users\mike_\Dropbox\Projects\Chess\chess.exe (executable)
 C:\Users\mike_\Dropbox\Projects\Chess\fontmanager.dll (jdk_library)
 C:\Users\mike_\Dropbox\Projects\Chess\freetype.dll (jdk_library)
 C:\Users\mike_\Dropbox\Projects\Chess\java.dll (jdk_library_shim)
 C:\Users\mike_\Dropbox\Projects\Chess\javaaccessbridge.dll (jdk_library)
 C:\Users\mike_\Dropbox\Projects\Chess\javajpeg.dll (jdk_library)
 C:\Users\mike_\Dropbox\Projects\Chess\jawt.dll (jdk_library)
 C:\Users\mike_\Dropbox\Projects\Chess\jsound.dll (jdk_library)
 C:\Users\mike_\Dropbox\Projects\Chess\jvm.dll (jdk_library_shim)
 C:\Users\mike_\Dropbox\Projects\Chess\lcms.dll (jdk_library)
========================================================================================================================
Finished generating 'chess' in 46.1s.

>dir *.exe
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 3EE3-4511

 Directory of C:\Users\mike_\Dropbox\Projects\Chess

04/12/2024  14:10        34,979,840 chess.exe
               1 File(s)     34,979,840 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  1,912,119,099,392 bytes free

However I get errors when running the resulting exe.
>chess.exe
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()Ljava/awt/Toolkit;
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.jni.functions.JNIFunctions$Support.getMethodID(JNIFunctions.java:1848)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.jni.functions.JNIFunctions$Support.getMethodID(JNIFunctions.java:1833)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.jni.functions.JNIFunctions.GetStaticMethodID(JNIFunctions.java:449)
        at java.desktop@21.0.5/java.awt.Toolkit.initIDs(Native Method)
        at java.desktop@21.0.5/java.awt.Toolkit.initStatic(Toolkit.java:1421)
        at java.desktop@21.0.5/java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1393)
        at java.desktop@21.0.5/java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Component.java:624)
        at java.base@21.0.5/java.lang.Class.ensureInitialized(DynamicHub.java:604)
        at java.base@21.0.5/java.lang.Class.ensureInitialized(DynamicHub.java:604)
        at java.base@21.0.5/java.lang.Class.ensureInitialized(DynamicHub.java:604)
        at java.base@21.0.5/java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.ensureInitialized(DirectMethodHandle.java:288)
        at java.base@21.0.5/java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.internalMemberNameEnsureInit(DirectMethodHandle.java:336)

Would anyone with a little more experience be able to advise? I think it's something to do with native libraries being required for AWT calls but I'm not 100% sure what that is or how to fix it. Do I have to obtain java code for the AWT library and, if so, from where?
Sorry for the long question but I wanted to include everything.
Thanks for reading
Mike
What I tried and expected:

I obviously downloaded native-image.
I looked at the various examples.
I read elsewhere that other users had issues with AWT and JNI but no real answers given.
I tried getting native-image to work with my other Java projects but they're a little more complicated and create additional issues.
I also tried the launch4J tool to produce an exe but it seemed to want to install Java on users PC's.
What was I expecting? From the examples given I was expecting to point the native-image app at my working jar and obtain a working exe.


I have no experience with this, but got curious and by googling the error text I found a graal issue. Someone proposed a build setup to try: oracle - graal - issue 3659 - tlf30 May 8th 23. Have you tried this as well? Apparently the application might still need libraries. Hope this helps. It seems to be an open problem, that this is not straightforward, still.

I tried the various suggestions in that thread though they didn't work for me or for the poster in that thread. I didn't try the maven and gradel approaches as I'm not sure what they are and they didn't work for that poster either. Thanks for looking.
